Setting up an API key under a paid account
Currently calling the following API end point using an API key under a free account.
End point - https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/search/6.2/geocode.json
So recently we created a new account with credit card details and created a new project and app which generated an API key. However, when I try to run service with new API key I get error.
Could you please assist.
Error "406Not AcceptableRequest:"
Thanks
Nick
Success response

Details on what API you are trying to use (Because all APIs have different syntax/features/documentation/etc) and the language of code/script you are attempting to use the API in, and the code used that is experiencing failure, AND finally, tags on your post for all of the above would be helpful in getting you an answer. As it stands, you've given us nothing more than "I made an api account somewhere and its not working".

There's already a v7 API and the endpoints also have changed. Please read the documentation and/or migration guide, before asking questions: https://www.here.com/docs/category/geocoding-search-v7

Hi, When I run the following via a browser using free API key I get success...                 https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/search/6.2/geocode.json?apiKey=FREEAPIKEY&searchtext=oak%20au%202222%20vic%20Australia

However, when I use paid API key I gey the following error.             {
"details": "invalid credentials for ",
"additionalData": [],
"type": "PermissionError",
"subtype": "InvalidCredentials"
}

Please use the edit function, not comments. While it's entirely unclear, how you even request and what you request; provide the code without the API key. Else this equals "it's not working", which is not an error description. You've obviously still haven't read the documentation, as suggested.

This is the working URL with free API key.      https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/search/6.2/geocode.json?apiKey=gaxDOGKswJYno9688bo8r6EWfzZQAArdOl-3Qqo6TTc&searchtext=23%20abc%20St%20AU%203193%20VIC%20Australia

when I use API key for paid account, I get {
"details": "invalid credentials for ",
"additionalData": [],
"type": "PermissionError",
"subtype": "InvalidCredentials"
}

Thanks Martin. Are you able to point me to developer documentation that points me to the latest version of the following APIs....    https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes   &    https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/search/6.2/geocode.json

This is only an educated guess, since the questions is kind of unclear.
But according to the documentation, you may have to configure trusted domains. This is a common feature, to prevent abuse of API keys, where the requests would count towards the quota and bill. Disabling this feature is therefore not suggested. It may take up to 30 minutes until changes will be applied. And you're also using an outdated version; that's 7.2 by now.

Voting to close and providing an answer... bold move

Would have retracted the vote, but was too slow. And pointing to the documentation is the best I can do. While I'm rather certain that this is the culprit; free API keys do not have this domain restriction, while paid API keys often do.

Mostly in jest, I've been smacked down for similar (though I suggest making such answers into wiki posts). Downvote isn't me though, don't you hate that

I think my answer will solve his problem and I can take quite some downvotes.
